# How to disable GUI on boot in 18.04 (Bionic Beaver)?

Tags: xorg, window-manager, gdm, wayland

It appears that `sudo systemctl disable gdm3 && sudo systemctl disable gdm` do not work in 18.04 to disable the windowing system at bootup.  What's the method for doing this now?

Comment: You messed up `sysctl` with `systemctl`. Please read their man-pages ([`man 8 sysctl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/sysctl.8.html) and [`man systemctl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/systemctl.1.html)).

Comment: LOL, you're right, I did it right on the system, but I simply typed it wrong here. Fixed.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

To disable GUI on boot, run:

```
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

To enable GUI again issue the command:

```
sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

To start Gnome session on a system without a current GUI just execute:

```
sudo systemctl start gdm3.service
```

Comment: It works but there is one problem. The screen is now pretty small in VirtualBox

Comment: How do you shutdown gdm once started manually?

Comment: Doesn't work for me: 'Failed to set default target: Unit file user-multi.target does not exist.'

Comment: @michid That's because you flipped `user` and `multi`

Comment: On my system, this produces the text 'The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy, RequiredBy, Also, Alias
settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance for template units).
This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.'   So...?

Comment: And to query the current setting use `sudo systemctl get-default`

Comment: In my case, I needed to find a way to disable GUI after I removed a graphics card from my server. This worked great.

Answer (score 4):

To answer @nurp's [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056363/how-to-disable-gui-on-boot-in-18-04-bionic-beaver#comment1767841_1056371)

> The screen is now pretty small in VirtualBox .

1. update your `/etc/default/grub` accordingly:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
   GRUB_GFXMODE=1152x864x32
   GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1152x864x32
   ```
2. run `sudo update-grub`.

   > - `nomodeset` so that the kernel does not attempt changing the resolution set by GRUB.
   > - `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX` if this variable is set, it controls the video mode in which the Linux kernel starts up, replacing the ‘vga=’ boot option.

#### References

- https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/gfxpayload.html

Answer (score 1):

To shutdown gdm once started manually..

You simply execute:

```
sudo systemctl stop gdm3.service
```

Comment: That's what I would have expected, but it doesn't appear to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the:

```
sudo systemctl stop gdm3.service
```

Not appearing to do anything commented by binarymelon

I can only assume you are doing this in the command line interface outside of the GUI... and you are receiving no response because the GUI service is already closed.

Alternatively, (what took many hours to learn and much longer to understand)...

I have found that everything depends on what you have done... for instance, installing `lightdm` with no “`core`” or whatever will result in faulty "GUI-ness"...
If you are indeed running the above command line interface instruction from a terminal within the GUI it will most certainly do something...
Mind you, this is my experience in 18.04.

If you are using `gdm3` then it will close and be just a (what I call an old-timey) cursor in the top left... and if you aren’t using `gdm3` then it will say:

```
Failed / not loaded
```

**Note and helpful hint:**
If u find yourself having stopped the service and still have no command line interface to type new commands on, try:
<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>.

This is your one-stop shopping for the killing/shutdown of the GUI that is loaded no matter what it is... even if your password isn’t being accepted.

I know this to be true because if you attempt to restart the GUI “too soon” a.k.a while it is still in the process of closing/stopping, service/shutting down the GUI, then, in my experience the CLI will alert you to this fact and ask you to try again in a bit.