# nvidia-173 on Ubuntu/Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: nvidia, graphics, kubuntu

I have an old 'Nvidia Quadro FX 1300' which works with full specs in MS Windows Vista/7.

Since there is no recent posts related to this subject, I shall reopen the case.

I tried to use this graphics card with Ubuntu/Kubuntu 18.04, with mediocre success.
Some windows appears with black screens on it and it is impossible to use the basic capabilities that an average VGA card should give.
I would be very glad if it would function as a simple **VGA** card.

The following command:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-173
```

gives me as a final message the follows:

```
Unable to locate package nvidia-173
```

According to this, I ask: Is there a way to use this graphics card at least as a simple VGA card?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The driver is not in the Graphics Drivers PPA nor is it in the standard Repos that come enabled.  You will have to download the driver from https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/71303/en-us

Comment: @Terrance - Thank you for the tip which I was considered. I got the GPU on service, but frankly I don't know if it was due to the driver, as the process gave me an error.
In the main answer window, I made a report of the steps done in order to put the GPU fully working.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let me thanks to @Terrance the information he gave me on the previous comment.

**The process of installation succeeded and the graphics display works perfectly (so far)!**
However, I'm not sure if the driver was really installed, because there were some errors during the process. My intent here is to make a report of the **PROCESS** I made.

I must say, however, that the process I shall describe assumed all the possible risks, including the loss of data, the damage of the System and a possible full install of Kubuntu  18.04.
For those who want to try this, I strongly recommend a backup of its personal data!

**STEP 1**

It is always wise to read the information available before an attempt to do anything.
At this link (https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/71303/en-us ), the tab "Additional information" has some important information which is necessary to understand part of the installation process.
I strongly recommend README (http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/173.14.39/README/README.txt )

On "*Chapter 2. Minimum Software Requirement*" there are some software elements which must be verified/matched on Kubuntu 18.04:

**linux kernel version**: do a compare with supported versions:

```
sudo cat /proc/version
```

So far, there is no problem, as Kubuntu 18.04 kernel version is 4.15.0.

**X.Org**: do a compare with supported versions:

```
sudo Xorg -version
```

Here there is an issue. According to the driver supported versions, the last one declared is 1.15. Kubuntu 18.04 xorg version is 1.19.6, which is more recent and apparently don't comply with the versions for which the driver was made. However is said that "*Sometimes very recent versions are not supported immediately following release, but we aim to support all new versions as soon as possible.*"

**STEP 2**

Place 'NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-173.14.39-pkg2.run' on /Home/*User* folder, for commodity.

**STEP 3**

Enable Kubuntu 18.04 to start in [shell mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056363/how-to-disable-gui-on-boot-in-18-04-bionic-beaver).

```
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
(...)
sudo reboot
```

Disable (blacklist) nouveau ([see info here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-nouveau-nvidia-driver-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)).

```
sudo bash -c "echo blacklist nouveau > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf"
sudo bash -c "echo options nouveau modeset=0 >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf"
cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf
(...)
sudo reboot
```

**STEP 4**

Build the NVIDIA kernel module (I wonder if this was really necessary, as the compilation failed):

```
sudo apt install binutils
(...)
sudo apt install gcc
(...)
sudo apt install make
(...)
sudo apt install dkms       #Contribution by @Terrance
(...)
sudo reboot
```

**STEP 5**

(The moment of truth...) Autocompile and install 'NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-173.14.39-pkg2.run'.

```
sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-173.14.39-pkg2.run
(...)
Building kernel module error
#Compilation didn't succeed - WTF!!!!
```

At this moment I gave up! I was prepared to a clean install of Kubuntu 18.04.

**STEP 6**

Replace the GUI interface:

```
sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
(...)
sudo reboot
```

**STEP 7**

Funny thing!
**The system booted with a perfect GUI which I've never seen!**
After several tests, everything was working perfectly and with no lags.

In conclusion, what were the processes I left with no recovery?

the Xorg and the nouveau, I think.

**CONCLUSION**

I'm not a technician, and frankly I don't really care what happened in technical terms that lead to put my `NVIDIA Quadro FX 1300` back to work on Kubuntu 18.04.
Maybe some technicians can answer to those questions in detail. Is up to them.

The fact is that that old graphics card is working and for me it's great!
Probably this process may function on any nvidia-173 GPU. However, that testings will be for someone who wants to give a try using this process.

I hope, however, that the system be stable enough after a new Kubuntu upgrade.

Cheers.

Comment: Good answer!  You might need to install `dkms` before running the installation of the NVIDIA drivers to help with inserting the kernel module for the video card.  But for the most part it sounds as though you got yours working.  Good job!  =)

Comment: Perhaps installing `dkms` on step 4? Anyway, since this thing began to work, I rather prefer not to do anything more. I spent almost 4 days around this, with almost 10 reinstalls. Time to rest a while :)

Comment: Sure, step 4 should work for that.  I don't blame you for not wanting to do anymore.  "Don't fix if it ain't broke!"  :)  Just add the step in there of the `sudo apt install dkms` and you should be fine.  :)

Comment: I don't think this is a good answer at all. It's not even clear the driver got installed, and saying "I don't really care what happened in technical terms" is just nonsense.

Answer (score -1):

***Hello***

I have solved this issue for (NVIDIA GeForce FX 5200) which has the same driver package as (Nvidia Quadro FX 1300)

***Problem***: Can not install the driver 173.14.39 for Graphics Card Model NVIDIA GeForce FX 5200.

***Solution***: I have searched and read for a solution for this issue for many days. nvidia-173 (173.14.39) is the driver package for NVIDIA GeForce FX 5200 graphics card. I have followed these sources to Install nVidia GeForce FX 5200 driver in Lubuntu 14.04.1 and it WORKED. Games (AssultCube) and (Warzone 2100) runs smoothly now. Here is the pure solution with technical details:

**nVidia site says**: "Support for X.Org xserver version 1.15 was added to the 173.14.* legacy driver series with version 173.14.39. No further releases from the 173.14.* series are planned."
Look here: https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3142/~/support-timeframes-for-unix-legacy-gpu-releases
Supported cards for 173.14.39 driver: https://www.nvidia.com/object/IO_32667.html
And here: https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/71302/en-us

**On Ubuntu forums site**: The latest version of Ubuntu that will support the 173.xx driver is Ubuntu 14.04.1.
Look here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2293379

If you are doing a new Ubuntu installation, do not install any version above 14.04.1, and do not download any updates during installation.

***First you must connect to internet and check that by browsing web pages for example.***

**To install from desktop:**

1. Go to Synaptic package manager then update package info.
2. Go to Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers-> select nvidia 
   driver 173.14.39 -> Apply.
3. Once the driver is downloaded and installed, reboot your computer.

**To Install from terminal:**

1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get install nvidia-173
3. sudo reboot

You can fully update your system to 14.04.6 and it won't destroy nVidia's dependencies. it'll still be using the 14.04.1 kernel series and graphics stack. Don't upgrade your distribution above 14.04.
To remove nVidia driver from the system: sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-* .
 You can also install (Linux Mint 17.1). I think it has X.Org xserver version 1.15 and will work too.
[Look at this screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOsbv.png)